# How getOutputStream() of Socket from another class?

Tags: android, sockets

I have two classes:

- **MainActivity.class**
- **ScreenCapture.class**

and want `getOutputStream();` from a Socket that is located on **MainActivity.class**.

Then i do:

```
MainActivity.INSTANCE.clientSocket.getOutputStream();
```

but is failing in this line ^, i not left logcat here because my logcat not is catching all events correctly, but from this description hope that someone can help.

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final MainActivity INSTANCE = new MainActivity();

 public Socket clientSocket;

    private final int SERVERPORT = 101;
    private final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.15.13";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////// CLIENTSOCKET //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {

                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                new Thread(new CommsThread()).start();

            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.toString());
            }

        }
    }

    class CommsThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                System.out.println("Waiting for server request");

                while(clientSocket.isConnected()){

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true);

                    if (reader.ready()) {
                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            System.out.println(line);

                            if(line != null && !line.trim().isEmpty()) {

                                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("screen")){

                                   // Do something

                                    out.flush();

                                }

                                if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                System.out.println("Shutting down Socket!!");
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                System.out.println(e1.toString());
            }

        }

    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
    }
```

*ScreenCapture*

```
public class ScreenCaptureClass {

   @UiThread
   public boolean takeScreenshot(@NonNull Context context) {

       //...

    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new OnImageAvailableListener() {

     @Override
     public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(final Void... params) {

        // ...

        OutputStream outs = MainActivity.INSTANCE.clientSocket.getOutputStream(); // <= Error is here

        }

       }

     }

    }

   }

 }
```

Comment: @Héctor, `new MainActivity()` also not worked.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that you **can't** create an instance like that

Comment: You did not say how and where you call the ScreenCaptureClass.

Comment: `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream())),true);`. Put those statements before the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass the socket's reference to your ScreenCaptureClass, you can try the following things:

- You can pass your socket through the `ScreenCaptureClass` constructor (probably the best way).
- Inside your `ScreenCaptureClass` you can add a static variable like `private static OutputStream outputStream` and a setter called from your MainActivity :

  ```
  public static void setOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
      outputStream = os;
  }
  ```

Comment: The network code in the ScreenCaptureClass should also be executed in a thread.

Comment: @greenapps, but `Runnable` class already not is a thread? you is talking about code of connection or code that send file?

Comment: Sorry.. i did not see that AsyncTask there. So its ok.

Comment: @greenapps, ok. Now i dont know if you already knew, but to send anything via socket through `Runnable` class comes  a exception `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, at least here in my tests.

Comment: Except that not be `Runnable` in my case :-)